# Good book to study and implement a Recommender system using big data technology like Mahout/hadoop/HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am searching for a good book to study and implement recommender systems. I tried to follow the recommender systems course offered at coursera but I could not work on it because I was really busy with other work. I want a good book to study and implement a full fledged recommender system. A book, because with that I can manage reading and working on it when-ever I want. 
Also, I want use mahout/hadoop in implementing it. So a book that will guide me through architecture using mahout apis step-by-step would really help.

Comment: (This is however probably off topic for SO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the book you want is [Mahout in Action](http://manning.com/owen/). I'm a coauthor and don't mind recommending it to you since I think it directly addresses your points: Mahout APIs, Hadoop, steps to implementing a recommender.

Comment: Oh, actually I've just begun reading that book. Thanks!